# When I run I get an InvalidOperationException when I try to write out the XML file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, streamwriter

I have a parent class PartNumber and two child classes PartNumberChild1 and PartNumberChild2.  In my main a create a PartNumberContainer and added two child one objects and two child 2 objects, I would like to store the different child classes in the list of PartNumber in the PartNumberContainer class and the write and read the PartNumberContainer in XML.

When I run I get an InvalidOperationException when I try to write out the XML file.

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(PartNumberChild1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(PartNumberChild2))]
public class PartNumber
{
  private string partNumber = "";
  public abstract ClassType;

  public PartNumber()
  {
  }
  public PartNumber(string partNod)
  {
    partNumber = partNo;
  }
  public string PartNumber
  {
    get { return partNumber; }
    set { partNumber = value; }
  }
}

[Serializable]
Public class PartNumberChild1 : PartNumber
{
  private string subPartNumber;
  private string classType = "Child1";

  public PartNumberChild1(string partNo, string subPartNo)
  :base(partNo)
  {
    subPartNumber = subPartNo;
  }

  public PartNumberChild1()
  {
  }

  public string SubPartNumber
  {
    get { return subPartNumber; }
    set { subPartNumber = value; }
  }
  public string ClassType
  {
    get { return classType; }
    set { classType = value; }
  }

}

[Serializable]
Public class PartNumberChild2 : PartNumber
{
  private string subPartNumber;
  private string classType = "Child2";

  public PartNumberChild1(string partNo, string subPartNo)
  :base(partNo)
  {
    subPartNumber = subPartNo;
  }

  public PartNumberChild2()
  {
  }

  public string SubPartNumber
 {
    get { return subPartNumber; }
    set { subPartNumber = value; }
 }

 public string ClassType
 {
    get { return classType; }
    set { classType = value; }
 }

}

[Serializable]
public class PartNumberContainer
{

  public static string PART_NUMBER_FILENAME_NAME = " Part_Numbers.xml";
  private List<PartNumber> partNumbers;
  public PartNumberContainer()
  {
    partNumbers = new List<PartNumber>();
  }
  public List<PartNumber> PartNumbers
  {
    get { return partNumbers; }
    set { partNumbers = value; }
  }
  public void AddPartNumber(PartNumber partNo)
  {
    partNumbers.Add(partNo);
  }
  public void AddPartNumber(string partNo)
  {
    partNumbers.Add(new PartNumber(partNo));
  }

  public void WriteMeToFile()
   {
    try
    {
```

I get the Error on this line.

```
      XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(PART_NUMBER_FILENAME_NAME);
        writer.Flush();
        x.Serialize(writer, this);

        writer.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Exception", "Error Message",       MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
}

public static PartNumberContainer ReadMeFromFile()
{
  PartNumberContainer fileData = new PartNumberContainer();
  object myObj = fileData;
  try
  {
    XMLFileReaderWriter.ReadConfigurationFile(ref myObj, GetConfigurationFileFolderPath(), PART_NUMBER_FILENAME_NAME);
  try
  {
      XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(myObj.GetType());
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(PART_NUMBER_FILENAME_NAME);
      myProperties = x.Deserialize(reader);
  }
  catch
  {
       MessageBox.Show("Exception", "Error Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
  }

    fileData = (PartNumberContainer)myObj;
  }
  catch
  {  // Error reading file
    MessageBox.Show(err, "Error Message", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
  }
  return fileData;

}

public MainWindow()
{
public static PartNumberContainer myPartNoContainer = new UUTPartNumberContainer();
  myPartNoContainer.AddPartNumber(new PartNumberChild1("onePartNo","OneSubPartNo"));
  myPartNoContainer.AddPartNumber(new PartNumberChild1("twoPartNo","twoSubPartNo"));
  myPartNoContainer.AddPartNumber(new PartNumberChild2("onePartNo","OneSubPartNo"));
  myPartNoContainer.AddPartNumber(new PartNumberChild2("twoPartNo","twoSubPartNo"));
  myPartNoContainer.WriteMeToFile();


 PartNumberContainer myPartNoContainerRead = PartNumberContainer.ReadMeFromFile();
 Foreach(PartNumber partNo in myPartNoContainerRead. PartNumbers)
{
  WriteLine(string.format(“The Part No = {0}, The subPartNumber = {1},     


the  ClassType = {2} “,partNo.PartNumber, partNo. SubPartNumber , partNo. ClassType )
}
```

Comment: And the exception says *what*?

Comment: Sorry "There was an error reflecting type PartNumberContainer and inner exception PartNumberChild1 cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: I know classes have to have a parameterless constructor before they can be serialized.  Since you're including those other 3 types, they may all need to have parameterless constructors as well.  Worth a shot.

Comment: I suspect this is due to misplaced attributes. The only relevant place for `[XmlInclude]` is in `PartNumber` declaration. Definitely **not** in `PartNumberContainer` as you have it right now. Also, `[Serializable]` is **not** related to XML serialization *whatsoever*.

Comment: @Ageonix Yes, this is an issue, too.

Comment: I think you're on the money though Ondrej.  I wasn't sure why the additional XmlInclude's were there either.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help.  Ondrej your first comment of what does the exception say got me digging into the exception more.  What I had to do was make both child classes public -- public class PartNumberChild2 : PartNumber and I had to add the constructor     
    public PartNumberChild2()
    {
    }

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was make both child classes public -- public class PartNumberChild2 : PartNumber and I had to add the constructor public PartNumberChild2() { }